# Parallax Scrolling Horizontal

Tags: html, parallax

Gostaria de uma explicação de como funciona o Parallax Scrolling Horizontal.

Efeito igual a [este site](http://www.xdawson.com/).

Comment: u_u eu faço um puta exemplo dahora e a resposta é duplicada uaheuhauehua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teoricamente é semelhante ao vertical, mas talvez ainda mais fácil.

Uma série de elementos são alinhados com `float:left`. Só um aparece na tela, com uma div com largura e altura de 100% e `overflow:hidden`. Tem um `scroll:none` no body também para não mostrar barras de rolagem.

Quando o mouse ou o teclado fazem o scroll, o body continua sem rolagem, mas o javascript vai diminuindo o left do próximo elemento até chegar a zero. Desta forma, ele fica por cima dos outros. Caso você volte, ou seja, navegue para o outro lado, o left chega a 100% e o elemento é deslizado para o outro lado.

Não sei se é assim que o plugin que você mostrou funciona, mas se eu fosse fazer do zero começaria a pensar desta forma.

**EDITADO**

Consegui fazer um exemplo em http://codepen.io/mapreuss/pen/yjozm que pode/deve ser melhorado, mas é só um exemplo.

No HTML coloquei um `data-attr="n"` em cada article para saber com qual elemento estou lidando.

No CSS só é importante deixar o `article` com `position:absolute`.

JS com jQuery:

```
// Configurações padrão
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Posicionamento dos segundos quadros
  $("article").each(function(i){
    if($(this).attr("data-index") != 1){
      $(this).css("left","100%");
    } else {
      // Se for o primeiro slide, adicione a classe ativo
      $(this).addClass("ativo");
    }
  });
});
// Ao apertar teclas chame as funções
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // esquerda
        back();
        break;

        case 38: // cima
        back();
        break;

        case 39: // direita
        go();
        break;

        case 40: // baixo
        go();
        break;

        default: return;
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
});

// Ao apertar para baixo ou para a direita
function go(){
  // Slide atual
  var ativo = parseInt($(".ativo").attr("data-index"));
  // Próximo slide
  var novo = ativo + 1;
  // o novo precisa ser menor que o total de slides
  var total = $("article").length;
  if (novo <= total){
  // Passa por cada slide
    $("article").each(function(i){
      // vê qual é o index atual
      var atual = parseInt($(this).attr("data-index"));
      // se o index atual for igual ao novo
      if($(this).attr("data-index") == novo){
        // o novo vem por cima, então mudar o z-index        
        $(this).css("z-index",1);
        // põe o slide com left 0
        $(this).animate({
          left: "0",
        }, 1500 );        
        // determina que o slide é o ativo
        $(this).addClass("ativo");
      // se for o slide anterior
      } else if(atual < novo) {
        // passa o z-index pra zero, pra ficar atrás
        $(this).css("z-index","0");
        // tira a classe ativo
        $(this).removeClass("ativo");
      // se o slide for o próximo
      } else if(atual > novo){
        // deixa o left com 100%
        $(this).css("left","100%");
      }
    });
  }
}

// Ao apertar para cima ou para a esquerda
function back(){
  // Slide atual
  var ativo = parseInt($(".ativo").attr("data-index"));
  // Slide anterior
  var novo = ativo - 1;
  // O novo precisa ser > 0 porque se for 0 não deve acontecer nada
  if(novo > 0){
    // Passa por cada slide
    $("article").each(function(i){
      // vê qual é o index atual
      var atual = parseInt($(this).attr("data-index"));
      // se o index atual for igual ao novo
      if($(this).attr("data-index") == novo){
        // o novo está em baixo então o z-index dele é zero
        // põe o slide com left 0 sem ninguém ver
        $(this).css({
          "z-index":0,
          "left":0  
        });       // determina que o slide é o ativo
        $(this).addClass("ativo");
      // se for o slide anterior
      } else if(atual < novo) {
        // passa o z-index pra zero, pra ficar atrás
        $(this).css("z-index","0");
        // tira a classe ativo
        $(this).removeClass("ativo");
      // se o slide for o próximo
      } else if(atual > novo){
        // faz animação para sair
        $(this).animate({
          left: "100%",
        }, 1500 );      
       }
    });
  }  
}
```

Tentei deixar explicadinho nos comentários. Parece um blocão de código mas se você ler aos poucos, faz sentido.

(Sei que dá pra escrever isso de um jeito mais bonito, repetindo bem menos código, mas tô com pressa. De qualquer forma toda sugestão é bem-vinda)

Comment: Teria algum exemplo. Tentei aqui e não consegui.

Comment: Vou fazer e atualizo a resposta, perai.